# NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval not calling selector (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

I have tried many approaches that I have found in other questions and any of them are working. My problem is that the timer is not calling selector

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController{
    var progressBarTimer = NSTimer()
    @IBOutlet weak var progress_bar: UIProgressView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.progress_bar.progress = 0
        self.progressBarTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(MyViewController.updateProgress(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        //also tried and redefining the updateProgress without timer parameter:
        /*
        *self.progressBarTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(MyViewController.updateProgress), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        */
    }
    func updateProgress(timer:NSTimer!) {
        progress_bar.progress += 0.1
        if (progress_bar.progress >= 1) {
           progressBarTimer.invalidate()
        }

    }
}
```

I have tried to do

```
progressBarTimer.fire()
```

and it just executes once the updateProgress function.

Could anyone shed light on? I would really appreciate

Comment: I tried your code and it's working fine, it's calling updateProgress method every second.

Comment: So, why is not working for me? Could be that I am calling other NSTimer in other ViewController before this one?

Comment: Have you tried with commenting all code in your updateProgress method and writing only print() statement?

Comment: Yes, and even debugging is not reaching that code

Comment: Have you check by putting breakpoint or print in updateProgress function?

Comment: Check my answer, I found the problem!Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replying to myself, I have found the problem. In the previous ViewController I am performing a segue after doing a http connection. In order to make it work, I have embedded the performSegue inside the dispatch:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goMySecondController", sender: nil)
})
```

In that second Controller is where I have the Timer that was not working. However, after this change is working properly.

Thanks for replies!

Answer (score 0):

You can call your function like this:

```
    let postes = ["1","2","3"]
    let timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: "playProgressBar:", userInfo: postes, repeats: true)
```

and function must like this:

```
func playProgressBar(timerSender : NSTimer) {

   //Do Somethings

}
```

Comment: Still not calling the selector. As I said to @Yuvrajsinh , I create another NSTimer in the previous ViewController, but I am invalidating it